# How to pull container image from docker registry to deploy azure container

Tags: azure, docker, azure-rm-template, azure-container-registry

I am currently working in a azure project where we need a way to push the image to public registries - it can be Azure ACR or docker registry.

Looks like Azure doesnt support anonymous read-access to Azure ACR. Hence only way is to push image to docker registry and pull the image form docker registry during container deployment in azure.

Is it possible? If so, how can I use azure template to achieve it? Any example please?

Answer (score 3):

I thinks it is possible to create the azure container by using `imageRegistryCredentials` property, you could refer to the sample template.

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "type": "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups",
  "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
  "location": "string",
  "tags": {},
  "properties": {
    "containers": [
      {
        "name": "string",
        "properties": {
          "image": "string",
          "command": [
            "string"
          ],
          "ports": [
            {
              "protocol": "string",
              "port": "integer"
            }
          ],
          "environmentVariables": [
            {
              "name": "string",
              "value": "string"
            }
          ],
          "resources": {
            "requests": {
              "memoryInGB": "number",
              "cpu": "number"
            },
            "limits": {
              "memoryInGB": "number",
              "cpu": "number"
            }
          },
          "volumeMounts": [
            {
              "name": "string",
              "mountPath": "string",
              "readOnly": boolean
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "imageRegistryCredentials": [
      {
        "server": "string",
        "username": "string",
        "password": "string"
      }
    ],
    "restartPolicy": "string",
    "ipAddress": {
      "ports": [
        {
          "protocol": "string",
          "port": "integer"
        }
      ],
      "type": "Public",
      "ip": "string",
      "dnsNameLabel": "string"
    },
    "osType": "string",
    "volumes": [
      {
        "name": "string",
        "azureFile": {
          "shareName": "string",
          "readOnly": boolean,
          "storageAccountName": "string",
          "storageAccountKey": "string"
        },
        "emptyDir": {},
        "secret": {},
        "gitRepo": {
          "directory": "string",
          "repository": "string",
          "revision": "string"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For more details, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerinstance/containergroups).

[image]

If the image is **public**, the password is not required.

[image]

Comment: how do u make image public ?

Comment: @ForeverLearner I think your question is out of the post theme, here is an [article](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/) for you to refer to, if my reply is helpful, you could mark it as answer to close it and ask the question of the usage of docker in another post. Thanks a lot.:-)